# Append template tag in vuetify from script

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

This is my current template tag

```
<template>
  <h1>View in 3D</h1>
</template>
```

in my script tag I have this code

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

It append the body in homepage, but I want the content in  template tag.

how to access current template tag component with vue?

Comment: with a `ref` is the `vue` way ... or an `id` or a distinct `class` .... eg using an ID ... `document.getElementById('someid').appendChild(renderer.domElement)` - a distinct class `document.querySelector('.someClass').appendChild(renderer.domElement)` - I'd show you how to use `ref` ... but you haven't specified a version of `vue`

Comment: I'm using vue 2. btw when I try to display it using {{ dataHtml }}. it show  [object HTMLCanvasElement]

Comment: sure, because `renderer.domElement` is not going to be a string, is it - it's going to be some sort of DOM element - I take it you completely ignored the rest of my comment after "ref"

Comment: by the way, if you did have HTML ... you'd use some element with `:html="dataHtml"` ... but you don't so you can't

Comment: I already try document.getElementById("model3d").appendChild(renderer.domElement) but it didnt show anything. I use getElementById inside mounted function() { this.$nextTick(function() { here}}

Answer (score 0):

After reading how to use ref, It was so simple how to appendChild using ref.
https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html